# Browser scrolling doesn't work in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: html, css, layout, internet-explorer-10

Here's test example from my project:
http://jsfiddle.net/g6aAd/6/

When tab content is very long, browser scrolling doesn't work in Internet Explorer 10.

Please advise how to fix it.

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

head, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
}

#main {
    background: #888; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 25px; 
    bottom: 0px; 
    width: 100%;
}

#head {
    background: #f8f; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 25px;
}

#left {
    background: #ff8;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%; 
}

#right {
    background: #8f8;
    margin-left: 250px; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100% !important; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        padding-left: 0px !important;
    }
}

.tab-content .well {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id='head'></div>
<div id='main'>
    <div id='left'></div>
    <div id='right'>
        <table style="height:100%;width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:100%;">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
                        <li class="active" style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <a>Tab #1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <a>Tab #2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <a>Tab #3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <a>Tab #4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <a>Tab #5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <a>Tab #6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <a>Tab #7</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:100%">
                <td style="height:100%;vertical-align:top;">
                    <div class="tab-content" style="overflow: visible;height:calc(100% - 58px);">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
                            <div class="well" style="height: 100%;">
                                <h1>
                                    These excellant intentions were strengthed when he enterd the Father Superior's diniing-room, though, stricttly speakin, it was not a dining-room, for the Father Superior had only two rooms alltogether; they were, however, much larger and more comfortable than Father Zossima's. 
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    But tehre was was no great luxury about the furnishng of these rooms eithar. The furniture was of mohogany, covered with leather, in the old-fashionned 
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    These excellant intentions were strengthed when he enterd the Father Superior's diniing-room, though, stricttly speakin, it was not a dining-room, for the Father Superior had only two rooms alltogether; they were, however, much larger and more comfortable than Father Zossima's. 
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    But tehre was was no great luxury about the furnishng of these rooms eithar. The furniture was of mohogany, covered with leather, in the old-fashionned 
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    These excellant intentions were strengthed when he enterd the Father Superior's diniing-room, though, stricttly speakin, it was not a dining-room, for the Father Superior had only two rooms alltogether; they were, however, much larger and more comfortable than Father Zossima's. 
                                    But tehre was was no great luxury about the furnishng of these rooms eithar. The furniture was of mohogany, covered with leather, in the old-fashionned 
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `border:0` from `#main` as it should be - I'm even surprised this does work as intended in Chrome since IE10 is without a doubt right here in its behaviour.

After that, please remove that `table`, we're not living in 1999 anymore.

Comment: 1) There's no border:0 in #main div.
2) I am trying to solve this problem during 3 days and have tried a lot of methods, but still can't do what I need. Can you please help me to implement it with divs, because I have absolutely no idea how to make it correctly(always appear different bugs).

Here's last changes:
http://jsfiddle.net/g6aAd/8/